# How many bytes are stored at a memory address?

Tags: memory, gdb, character, byte

I am very confused with the following gdb output. I am debugging a program that processes a text file. The first word in the file is "the" and the gdb output looks as follows:

"The":

```
(gdb) p *(char*)0x7fffffff9d30
$12 = 84 'T'

(gdb) p *(char*)0x7fffffff9d34
$13 = 104 'h'

(gdb) p *(char*)0x7fffffff9d38
$14 = 101 'e'
```

A character is one byte, so when I increase the address of 'T' by 8 bits I should find 'h' there. But the address of 'h' is *only 4 bits* farther. What am I missing here?

Didn't realize that these are Wchar_t (wide characters).

Comment: It is 4 *octets/bytes* further, not bits.

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused. First off this suggests the characters are being stored in 4 bytes (which is true, these aren't characters but wchar_t, i.e. wide characters). I'll edit the post to reflect that. BUT I also have a question. Does that mean that at each memory address there is entire byte of memory stored? i.e. 0x7fffffff9d30 references an entire byte and 0x7fffffff9d31 references a totally different byte?

Comment: A memory address doesn't include *what* object (or how much data) is stored at a given location. The compiler does (e.g. from the `wchar_t` type) and generates the appropriate offsets *when* it was compiled. Likewise, the usage of the data at said addresses has been compiled into the emitted target instructions.

Comment: (I'm not sure what magic GDB does in patching everything together or what it requires.)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in situations like this you might like to use the "x" command to dump memory.  This avoids any possible confusion caused by types and operators.